# Very slight noise that can be heard inside the cabin. I think it resembles the sound of a bearing. What could it possibly be?

Tags: noise

I have a Peugeot 406 Petrol (1.8 16V Engine).

When I sit in the car with the engine idling, I can barely hear a noise that I'm not sure where it is coming from.

I think it is similar to a bearing noise but I'm not sure. I opened the hood and listened carefully with a rubber hose (one end into my ear, the other end near any part that I suspect could be the culprit).

I checked alternator, idler pulleys, Belt tensioner, AC Compressor, Hydraulic pump and all around the engine but I didn't hear anything that sounds abnormally.

I thought maybe it comes from the gearbox but when I fully pressed the clutch (to prevent inner gearbox shafts from spinning), it made no difference.

The only thing that I can't inspect is the water pump bearing because it is inside timing cover and I don't have easy access to it.

What do you think about the noise?

Comment: please post an audio snapshot of the noise.

Comment: It is so low that I can't record it with any device. Some people don't hear it at all!

Comment: Ventilation fan?

Comment: No, I don't think it is ventilation fan because I changed its speed but the noise was still there. I turned the engine off and turned on ventilation fan but the noise disappeared!

Comment: Try opening just the right-side windows. Then open just the left side windows. Any difference? Then, with the brake on, load the engine while keeping the RPM slightly off-idle.

Comment: @John Canon This noise is more noticeable when I'm inside the cabin with all the windows up and the engine idling.

Comment: If we cant hear it, we can only guess.

Comment: So, what's your guess?

Comment: Does this car have an “Automatic” setting for the heater and A/C system?  If so there maybe a small motor/fan/temperature sensor sampling the temperature inside the passenger compartment.

Comment: No, it only has a manual air-conditioning system. I suspect the noise could also be related to something loose that rattles and makes noise.